# Php: Why does my code echo all values in the table rather than just a subset of those values?

Tags: php

My `category` table has the columns `cat_id`, `cat_name`, `user_id` and `time_stamp`.

I am trying to echo the `cat_name` rows that have a matching `user_id` of say `10`, but instead all the `cat_names` in the table are being echoed. Can you tell me why please?

The `user` table is queried correctly: `user_id` is the corresponding value of `username`:

```
    //here is the user_id, which is the corresponding user_id for username Joe Blogs
    echo $user_id;
```

I just can't understand why my code echoes all the `cat_names` in the whole table - and not only those `cat_names` associated with the `user_id`.

Here's my code:

```
 $Number = "Joe Blogs";

$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$stmt->bind_param('s', $Number) or die ("MySQLi-stmt binding failed ".$stmt->error);
$stmt->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt->error);
$result = $stmt->get_result();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //get the corresponding user_id in the row
    $user_id = $row["user_id"];

    //here is the user_id, which is the corresponding user_id for username Joe Blogs
    echo $user_id;
}

$sql = "SELECT cat_name FROM category WHERE $user_id = ?";

$stmt2 = $con->prepare($sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$stmt2->bind_param('i', $user_id) or die ("MySQLi-stmt binding failed ".$stmt2->error);
$stmt2->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt2->error);
$result2 = $stmt2->get_result();

while ($row[] = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data = $row;

    $json = json_encode($data);

} 

echo $json;
```

Comment: where $user_id = ? might be it.. remove the $

Comment: Should be `$sql = "SELECT cat_name FROM category WHERE user_id = ?";`

Comment: On the line: `$sql = "SELECT cat_name FROM category WHERE $user_id = ?";` you've put a `$` before `user_id`, was that intentional? You also defined `user_id` in your while loop, I don't know a lot of php but I suppose it won't be defined after, did you define it before the while loop?

Comment: Thanks guys, should have copped this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely this line

```
$sql = "SELECT cat_name FROM category WHERE $user_id = ?";
// specifically here                        ^
```

will equate to

```
SELECT cat_name FROM category WHERE 10 = 10
```

As `10 = 10` will always be true, it returns all rows from your table

Correct this line like so

```
$sql = "SELECT cat_name FROM category WHERE user_id = ?";
```

Comment: Damn! Thanks, I spent an hour and half looking at this! I was sure it was perfect...